# New JFrame Occasionally Blank in Risk Game Clone

Tags: java, swing, jframe, splash-screen

I am trying to create a risk clone game. Occasionally (every 20 times) after the splash screen goes away, the JFrame returns empty. This never occured before the Splash Screen was added.
e.g image of blank JFrame. The SplashScreen has this undesirable bug. It could be potentially something to do with threads but I am unsure. Any help woulod be greatly appreciated. I need an expert eye to see what I am missing.
[image: Blank JFrame]

vs what I'm supposed to see

[image: Supposed to see]

Main.java

```
//Group WhyNotBot
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    //constant variables to use

    static String playerOneName;
    static String playerTwoName;
    static boolean playerOneNameSet;
    static boolean nameSetUpDone= false;
    public static final int NUM_PLAYERS = 2;
    public static final int NUM_NEUTRALS = 4;
    public static final int NUM_PLAYERS_PLUS_NEUTRALS = NUM_PLAYERS + NUM_NEUTRALS;
    public static final int NUM_COUNTRIES = 42;
    public static final int INIT_COUNTRIES_PLAYER = 9;
    public static final int INIT_COUNTRIES_NEUTRAL = 6;
    public static final int INIT_UNITS_PLAYER = 36;
    public static final int INIT_UNITS_NEUTRAL = 24;
    public static final String[] COUNTRY_NAMES = {
            "Ontario","Quebec","NW Territory","Alberta","Greenland","E United States","W United States","Central America","Alaska",
            "Great Britain","W Europe","S Europe","Ukraine","N Europe","Iceland","Scandinavia",
            "Afghanistan","India","Middle East","Japan","Ural","Yakutsk","Kamchatka","Siam","Irkutsk","Siberia","Mongolia","China",
            "E Australia","New Guinea","W Australia","Indonesia",
            "Venezuela","Peru","Brazil","Argentina",
            "Congo","N Africa","S Africa","Egypt","E Africa","Madagascar"};  
    // for reference
    public static final int[][] ADJACENT = { 
            {4,1,5,6,3,2},    // 0
            {4,5,0},
            {4,0,3,8},
            {2,0,6,8},
            {14,1,0,2},
            {0,1,7,6}, 
            {3,0,5,7},
            {6,5,32},
            {2,3,22},
            {14,15,13,10},    
            {9,13,11,37},     // 10
            {13,12,18,39,10},
            {20,16,18,11,13,15},
            {15,12,11,10,9},
            {15,9,4},
            {12,13,14},
            {20,27,17,18,12}, 
            {16,27,23,18},
            {12,16,17,40,39,11},
            {26,22},
            {25,27,16,12},    // 20
            {22,24,25},        
            {8,19,26,24,21},
            {27,31,17},
            {21,22,26,25},
            {21,24,26,27,20},
            {24,22,19,27,25},
            {26,23,17,16,20,25},
            {29,30},          
            {28,30,31},
            {29,28,31},      // 30
            {23,29,30},
            {7,34,33},       
            {32,34,35},
            {32,37,35,33},
            {33,34},
            {37,40,38},      
            {10,11,39,40,36,34},
            {36,40,41},
            {11,18,40,37},
            {39,18,41,38,36,37},  //40
            {38,40}
    };
    public static final int NUM_CONTINENTS = 6;
    public static final String[] CONTINENT_NAMES = {"N America","Europe","Asia","Australia","S America","Africa"};  // for reference 
    public static final int[] CONTINENT_IDS = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5};
    public static final int[] CONTINENT_VALUES = {5,5,7,2,2,3};
    public static final int[][] COUNTRY_COORD = {
            {191,150},     // 0
            {255,161},
            {146,86},
            {123,144},
            {314,61},
            {205,235},
            {135,219},
            {140,299},
            {45,89},
            {370,199},
            {398,280},      // 10
            {465,270},
            {547,180},
            {460,200},
            {393,127},
            {463,122},
            {628,227},
            {679,332},
            {572,338},
            {861,213},
            {645,152},      // 20
            {763,70},
            {827,94},
            {751,360},
            {750,140},
            {695,108},
            {760,216},
            {735,277},
            {889,537},
            {850,429},
            {813,526},       // 30
            {771,454},
            {213,352},
            {221,426},
            {289,415},
            {233,523},
            {496,462},
            {440,393},
            {510,532},
            {499,354},
            {547,432},        // 40
            {586,545}
    };


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //default constructor
    public mainClass() {

    }

    //paint components 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        //set background color to white
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        if(nameSetUpDone ==false) {
            //iterating through array to correctly position nodes and country string names and colors
            for(int i =0; i<COUNTRY_COORD.length;i++) {

                //coloring the continents
                if(i<=8) {
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                }
                if(i>8 && i <=15) {
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                }
                if(i>=16 && i <=27) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);

                }if(i>=28 && i <=31) {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                }
                if(i>=32 && i <=35) {
                    g.setColor(Color.orange);
                }
                if(i>=36 && i <=41) {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                }

                //creating the circular nodes
                g.fillOval(COUNTRY_COORD[i][0],COUNTRY_COORD[i][1],20,20);  

                //setting the text color to black
                g.setColor(Color.black);

                //writing the country names
                g.drawString(COUNTRY_NAMES[i],(COUNTRY_COORD[i][0]-10),(COUNTRY_COORD[i][1]-10));

            }
        }else {
            
            // if nameSetUpDone is true i.e we are done setting up the names
            // then assign each player 9 territories and each of the 4 neutral players 6 territories
            
            for(int i =0; i<COUNTRY_COORD.length;i++) {
                //coloring the continents for each of the players
                if(i<=8) {
                    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                }
                if(i>8 && i <=17) {
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                }
                if(i>17 && i <=23) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);

                }if(i>23 && i <=29) {
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                }
                if(i>29 && i <=35) {
                    g.setColor(Color.orange);
                }
                if(i>35 && i <=41) {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                }
                //creating the circular nodes
                g.fillOval(COUNTRY_COORD[i][0],COUNTRY_COORD[i][1],20,20);  

                //setting the text color to black
                g.setColor(Color.black);

                //writing the country names
                g.drawString(COUNTRY_NAMES[i],(COUNTRY_COORD[i][0]-10),(COUNTRY_COORD[i][1]-10));

                //writing the armies underneath the names of the countries
                g.drawString("1",(COUNTRY_COORD[i][0]+-5),(COUNTRY_COORD[i][1]+30));
            }
        }


        //making the lines dashed
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(2, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{9}, 0);
        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        //diagonal lines intersecting nodes 
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[29][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[29][1], COUNTRY_COORD[31][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[31][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[29][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[29][1], COUNTRY_COORD[30][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[30][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[30][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[30][1], COUNTRY_COORD[31][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[31][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[30][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[30][1], COUNTRY_COORD[28][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[28][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[29][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[29][1], COUNTRY_COORD[28][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[28][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[23][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[23][1], COUNTRY_COORD[31][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[31][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[23][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[23][1], COUNTRY_COORD[27][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[27][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[23][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[23][1], COUNTRY_COORD[17][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[17][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[27][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[27][1], COUNTRY_COORD[17][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[17][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[17][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[17][1], COUNTRY_COORD[18][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[18][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[16][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[16][1], COUNTRY_COORD[17][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[17][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[27][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[27][1], COUNTRY_COORD[16][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[16][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[16][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[16][1], COUNTRY_COORD[18][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[18][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[12][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[12][1], COUNTRY_COORD[18][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[18][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[16][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[16][1], COUNTRY_COORD[12][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[12][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[16][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[16][1], COUNTRY_COORD[20][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[20][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[20][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[20][1], COUNTRY_COORD[27][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[27][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[12][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[12][1], COUNTRY_COORD[20][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[20][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[41][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[41][1], COUNTRY_COORD[38][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[38][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[41][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[41][1], COUNTRY_COORD[40][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[40][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[38][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[38][1], COUNTRY_COORD[40][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[40][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[38][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[38][1], COUNTRY_COORD[36][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[36][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[40][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[40][1], COUNTRY_COORD[36][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[36][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[37][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[37][1], COUNTRY_COORD[36][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[36][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[37][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[37][1], COUNTRY_COORD[40][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[40][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[37][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[37][1], COUNTRY_COORD[39][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[39][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[39][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[39][1], COUNTRY_COORD[40][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[40][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[39][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[39][1], COUNTRY_COORD[18][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[18][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[40][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[40][1], COUNTRY_COORD[18][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[18][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[32][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[32][1], COUNTRY_COORD[34][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[34][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[32][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[32][1], COUNTRY_COORD[33][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[33][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[34][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[34][1], COUNTRY_COORD[33][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[33][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[33][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[33][1], COUNTRY_COORD[35][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[35][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[34][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[34][1], COUNTRY_COORD[35][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[35][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[32][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[32][1], COUNTRY_COORD[7][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[7][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[7][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[7][1], COUNTRY_COORD[6][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[6][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[7][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[7][1], COUNTRY_COORD[5][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[5][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[6][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[6][1], COUNTRY_COORD[5][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[5][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[5][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[5][1], COUNTRY_COORD[1][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[1][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[1][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[1][1], COUNTRY_COORD[0][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[0][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[0][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[0][1], COUNTRY_COORD[3][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[3][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[5][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[5][1], COUNTRY_COORD[0][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[0][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[6][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[6][1], COUNTRY_COORD[0][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[0][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[6][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[6][1], COUNTRY_COORD[3][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[3][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[8][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[8][1], COUNTRY_COORD[3][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[3][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[2][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[2][1], COUNTRY_COORD[3][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[3][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[8][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[8][1], COUNTRY_COORD[2][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[2][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[0][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[0][1], COUNTRY_COORD[2][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[2][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[2][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[2][1], COUNTRY_COORD[4][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[4][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[1][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[1][1], COUNTRY_COORD[4][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[4][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[4][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[4][1], COUNTRY_COORD[14][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[14][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[4][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[4][1], COUNTRY_COORD[0][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[0][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[10][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[10][1], COUNTRY_COORD[11][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[11][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[10][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[10][1], COUNTRY_COORD[37][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[37][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[37][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[37][1], COUNTRY_COORD[11][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[11][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[11][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[11][1], COUNTRY_COORD[39][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[39][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[11][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[11][1], COUNTRY_COORD[13][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[13][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[13][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[13][1], COUNTRY_COORD[15][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[15][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[15][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[15][1], COUNTRY_COORD[12][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[12][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[14][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[14][1], COUNTRY_COORD[15][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[15][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[15][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[15][1], COUNTRY_COORD[9][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[9][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[14][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[14][1], COUNTRY_COORD[9][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[9][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[11][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[11][1], COUNTRY_COORD[12][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[12][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[10][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[10][1], COUNTRY_COORD[13][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[13][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[10][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[10][1], COUNTRY_COORD[9][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[9][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[9][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[9][1], COUNTRY_COORD[13][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[13][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[12][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[12][1], COUNTRY_COORD[13][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[13][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[27][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[27][1], COUNTRY_COORD[19][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[19][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[27][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[27][1], COUNTRY_COORD[26][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[26][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[19][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[19][1], COUNTRY_COORD[26][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[26][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[24][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[24][1], COUNTRY_COORD[26][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[26][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[25][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[25][1], COUNTRY_COORD[24][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[24][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[26][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[26][1], COUNTRY_COORD[25][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[25][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[25][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[25][1], COUNTRY_COORD[21][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[21][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[21][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[21][1], COUNTRY_COORD[19][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[19][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[22][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[22][1], COUNTRY_COORD[21][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[21][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[19][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[19][1], COUNTRY_COORD[22][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[22][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[24][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[24][1], COUNTRY_COORD[19][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[19][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[26][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[26][1], COUNTRY_COORD[20][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[20][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[24][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[24][1], COUNTRY_COORD[21][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[21][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[18][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[18][1], COUNTRY_COORD[11][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[11][1]);
        g.drawLine(COUNTRY_COORD[21][0]+10,COUNTRY_COORD[21][1], 1000, COUNTRY_COORD[22][1]);
        g.drawLine(0,COUNTRY_COORD[22][1], COUNTRY_COORD[8][0]+10, COUNTRY_COORD[8][1]);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SplashScreen();
        
        // title of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Risk");

        //Creating a text field
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JLabel welcome = new JLabel("");
        welcome.setFont (welcome.getFont ().deriveFont (20.0f));
        welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 1 in the text box at the bottom");
        frame.add(welcome,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //action listener listens for enter key
        textField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
            {

                //checks if player Ones name is set and sets player Twos name aswell
                if (!playerOneNameSet)
                {
                    playerOneName = textField.getText();
                    textField.setText("");
                    welcome.setText("Please Enter name for Player 2 in the text box at the bottom");
                    playerOneNameSet = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerTwoName = textField.getText();
                    textField.setText("");  
                    
                    //turning the nameSetUpDone to true as we are finished setting up the names
                    nameSetUpDone = true;
                    
                    // repainting as we want to update the screen
                    frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                    welcome.setText("Player One:" + playerOneName +" Player Two:" + playerTwoName + " Awaiting player one move");
                    
                }
            }
        });



        // make sure it closes correctly
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //frame size in pixels
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;    
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);

        // makes sure the frame is visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        mainClass main = new mainClass();
        frame.add(main);


    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }


}
```

SplashScreen.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SplashScreen {
    JFrame frameSplash;
    JLabel image=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("risk.jpg"));
    JLabel text=new JLabel("Risk By WhyNotBot");
    JProgressBar progressBar=new JProgressBar();
    JLabel message=new JLabel();
    SplashScreen()
    {
        createGUIForApp();
        addImageToJFrame();
        addTextToJPanel();
        addProgressBarToJFrame();
        addMessageToJFrame();
        runningPBar();
        frameSplash.dispose();
    }
    public void createGUIForApp(){
        frameSplash=new JFrame();
        frameSplash.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frameSplash.setUndecorated(true);
        frameSplash.setSize(600,400);
        frameSplash.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frameSplash.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frameSplash.setVisible(true);

    }
    public void addImageToJFrame(){
        image.setSize(600,200);
        frameSplash.add(image);
    }
    public void addTextToJPanel()
    {
        text.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,35));
        text.setBounds(170,220,600,40);
        text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        frameSplash.add(text);
    }
    public void addMessageToJFrame()
    {
        message.setBounds(250,320,200,40);
        message.setForeground(Color.black);
        message.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.BOLD,35));
        frameSplash.add(message);
    }
    public void addProgressBarToJFrame(){
        progressBar.setBounds(100,280,400,30);
        progressBar.setBorderPainted(true);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        progressBar.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        frameSplash.add(progressBar);
    }
    public void runningPBar(){
        int i=0;

        while( i<=100)
        {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(25);
                progressBar.setValue(i);
                message.setText("LOADING "+Integer.toString(i)+"%");
                i++;
                if(i==100 || i>98)
                    frameSplash.dispose();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AWT and Swing methods are not thread-safe.  They must execute in only one thread:  the AWT Event Dispatch Thread.  Move the entire contents of your `main` method into a separate private method, and call it from [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)).  Failure to do so will mean your program will work sometimes, but not all the time.  Observe the threading rules and it will work every single time.

Comment: Note that there is an AWT based [`SplashScreen`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) for good reason. That reason is that it can be loaded and on-screen before the JRE has to load the Swing library, and is therefore faster.

Comment: **General tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.